# Create a facebook poll from an iPhone app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to post a question (poll, with vote options) to my Facebook wall from an iphone app using the Facebook graph-api? I need to get fellow users votes to such a question and be able to read them back in the application. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can do questions via the graph API. See  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/question/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/question_option/

As with many objects in the graph, you can HTTP Post (create), HTTP Get (read), Http Delete (remove), questions.

See an example here:  https://graph.facebook.com/723026073/questions

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I'll look that up, should hopefully get my head around it as there is no sample code i could find on that topic.

Comment: For the most part, working with the graph API is pretty standard (with exceptions).   So if you already can Post, Get, and Delete other graph objects, then working with questions should be identical.  Happy coding!!